# Example using Object lock synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's my attempt at trying to understand `synchronized()` blocks using an Object lock, using `wait()` and `notify()`:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SyncTest {

    private Scanner scanner;
    private Object lock;
    private volatile String string;

    public SyncTest() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        lock = new Object();
        string = "";
    }

    public void start() {

        //This thread will wait until the other thread notifies it.
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        try {
                            lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("String changed.");
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();

        //This thread will notify Thread 1 if a condition is met.
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (!string.isEmpty()) {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            lock.notify();
                        }
                        string = "";
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();

        //This is just a dummy thread to modify the string data.
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    string = scanner.nextLine();
                }
            }
        });
        t3.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SyncTest().start();
    }

}
```

Couple questions:

1. Is there any better way of achieving such functionality?
2. Is this how listeners work? How are they so efficient at listening to events? I mean, if I don't add the 200ms delay in `t2` execution, the thread will consume a lot of processing power, so, how can I create a listener behavior?

Comment: As for #2: Beware that a listener is nothing more than an object instance that has one or more methods that get called by the object instance that it has been passed to. In principle, a listener does not have to do any multithreading: the code that is run by the listener is generally run in the thread of the method that calls it. And for #1, yes, we use `java.util.concurrent`. If you're doing locking yourself, you're likely reinventing some threaded wheel.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, so, for example, what's the best way of constantly checking if a variable "changes" to trigger some kind of action?

Comment: What you're probably looking for is a "Monitor". Although `java.util.concurrent` doesn't have a `Monitor` class it does have, for instance, `ReentrantLock`, see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-concurrency-%E2%80%93-part-5) for a (seemingly good) explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look sound to me with one exception that you need to be aware of, as far as I can see:

```java
if (!string.isEmpty()) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.notify();
    }
    string = "";
}
```

The moment you set `string` to a new value, the first thread might not have visited the variable at this point. You can see that when outputting `string` in both threads. This is only important if thread #1 is going to do processing on the value.

Additionally, because of the `Thread.sleep(200);` you might miss input lines because `string` value might have changed an unidentified number of times during this period.

---

> I mean, if I don't add the 200ms delay in t2 execution, the thread will consume a lot of processing power, so, how can I create a listener behavior?

The same way you did between #2 and #1, `notify` #2 from #3.

---

To fix these issues, you want to use something like a `BlockingQueue`. Thread #3 pushes the line to the `Queue`, thread #2 dequeues the next value and notifies #1. Or, #2 pushes it to a second `Queue` for #1.